# Trouble with Timestamp Communication Between Master and Slave Sockets in C

Tags: c, windows, sockets, winsock

I have two functions in C that involve communication between a master and slave socket. The master sends a timestamp to the slave using the sendSyncMessage function, while the slave receives it using receiveSyncMessage. The master produces the correct output (e.g., "2023-12-07 11:07:03"), but the slave returns error code 10014.

The IP address for both master and slave is 127.0.0.1, port is 4455.

The master produces the correct output, but the slave returns error code 10014. I suspect there's an issue with how `recvfrom`is used. Can someone help me identify and resolve the problem?

```
void sendSyncMessage(SOCKET clientSocket, struct sockaddr_in client_address)
{
    SYSTEMTIME systemTime;
    char buffer[1024];

    GetLocalTime(&systemTime);

    sprintf(buffer, "SYNC:%04d-%02d-%02d %02d:%02d:%02d",  systemTime.wYear, systemTime.wMonth, systemTime.wDay,
        systemTime.wHour, systemTime.wMinute, systemTime.wSecond);

    printf("The current timestamp : %s\n", buffer);

    sendto(clientSocket, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0, (struct sockaddr*)&client_address, sizeof(client_address));
}

void receiveSyncMessage(SOCKET server_socket)
{
    struct sockaddr_in server_address;
    int server_address_size = sizeof(server_address);
    char buffer[1024];

    int bytesReceived = recvfrom(server_socket, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0, (struct sockaddr*)&server_address, server_address_size);
    if (bytesReceived == SOCKET_ERROR) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Receive failed: %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
    }
    else{
        buffer[bytesReceived] = '\0';
        printf("Received Sync timestamp: %s\n", buffer);
        printf("Bytes received: %d\n", bytesReceived);
     }    
}
```

Comment: Please confirm that your actual question is _"Why does `recvfrom`  trigger a 10014 error"_

Comment: Maybe this helps: stackoverflow.com/questions/861154/winsock-error-code-10014

Comment: How can you have two sockets with the same IP and port?

Comment: Yes, why does recvfrom return error 10014? because sendto is providing the timestamp output but recvfrom is not

Comment: One socket is for sending and one socket is for receiving the data

Answer (score 1):

In your `recvfrom` call you are passing `server_address_size`, but the `recvfrom` function requires a *pointer* for that parameter.  You should be passing `&server_address_size` to avoid the invalid pointer error (code 10014).

Also, it appears you are using UDP, so I'm basing this part on that assumption:  The *server* component will normally use an IP and a known port number (so that clients can find it).  The *clients* will use an IP and port 0 -- allowing the system to assign a random, unused port number that will not conflict with existing sockets. Then the server will respond to the IP:Port it gets in the recvfrom() call when it receives a request from the client.

OTOH, if your *server* is just broadcasting a time sync network-wide, to a known port, then your *server* should use Port 0 and your clients (each on a different IP) would use the same known port the server is sending *to*.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I changed my recvfrom() function as you suggested but now the slave code doesn't end without any output. It had to be stopped by interrupting the execution.

Comment: I have a single server and client. I tried configuring both with the same port and IP. Server was able to note the timestamp but the client was unable to receive the timestamp because of the error 10014. I tried changing the pointer value as you suggested and also tried this part of code sizeof(client_address) instead of &client_address_size and noted that the program does not stop